# ASP.NET MVC 5 ApplicationUser as foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

What I would like to be able to do is update the UserContent table any time a user visits a content page. I created a controller to try and manually input data before implementing this but I am getting a foreign key error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.UserContent_dbo.IdentityUser_ApplicationUserId". The conflict occurred in database "COMPILING_a6a38dac907c4816af896bbeb6cdaa55", table "dbo.IdentityUser", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Model:

```
public class UserContent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Times Visited")]
    public int Visited { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Rating")]
    public byte Rating { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Content Page")]
    public int ContentID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User")]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Content Content { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
private CompilingContext db = new CompilingContext();
private ApplicationDbContext db2 = new ApplicationDbContext();  

public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="ID,Visited,Rating,ContentID,ApplicationUserId")] UserContent usercontent)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.UserContent.Add(usercontent);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ApplicationUserId = new SelectList(db2.Users, "Id", "UserName", usercontent.ApplicationUserId);
        ViewBag.ContentID = new SelectList(db.Contents, "ID", "Title", usercontent.ContentID);
        return View(usercontent);
    }
```

Comment: At the point db.UserContent.Add(usercontent); is called, what is the state of usercontent?  Does it have a valid ApplicationUserId?

Comment: @BrendanGreen it is an id that matches the user that is in the AspNetUsers table.

I also looked at the IdentityUser table and it is empty. I don't know if it is supposed to be since I'm having a hard time finding resources on MVC 5.

Comment: That would be the problem.  Without knowing much detail about your model, you have a FK on ApplicationUserId in UserContent that points to the Id column in the IdentityUser table.  If IdentityUser is empty, this is the error that you'd receive. See this resource for details on ASP.NET Identity: http://www.asp.net/identity

Comment: Fixed it by putting everything into the same context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by putting all of my models into one context. I originally had them in two separate contexts which was causing issues as it was giving me two separate databaes.